# Sparse matrix in Sage

Tags: python, matrix, sparse-matrix, sage

So I have a really big matrix of n = 70.000 full of RDF. This is of course not possible with a normal matrix. So I want to use some form of sparse matrix, the elements in the columns of the matrix are in a lot of cases 0 or all the same low RDF.

Like for example:

```
0   | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0
0   | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.1
0.1 | 0   | 0   | 0.1
0   | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0
```

In this example the fist column has 3 times 0, the second 3 times 0.1, ...

How can I initialize such a matrix in Sage/Python?

Answer (score 2):

Sage's sparse matrices won't take advantage of the fact that the nonzero entries are duplicated, but they will take advantage of the fact that there aren't many nonzero entries. To define one, use a dictionary with keys being pairs of integers `(row, column)`:

```
sage: m = matrix(4, 4, {(1, 1): 2.1, (2,3): -0.5})
sage: m
[ 0.000000000000000  0.000000000000000  0.000000000000000  0.000000000000000]
[ 0.000000000000000   2.10000000000000  0.000000000000000  0.000000000000000]
[ 0.000000000000000  0.000000000000000  0.000000000000000 -0.500000000000000]
[ 0.000000000000000  0.000000000000000  0.000000000000000  0.000000000000000]
sage: type(m)
<type 'sage.matrix.matrix_generic_sparse.Matrix_generic_sparse'>
sage: m.is_sparse()
True
```

You can also convert any matrix from dense to sparse using `mat.sparse_matrix()`, and there is a corresponding method `mat.dense_matrix()` for the other conversion.

Answer (score 0):

scipy has sparse matrices. You can either choose a sparse row or column matrix.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html